# Problem with JavaScript attack string in next badge popup

Tags: bug, profile-page, user-interface, popups

I was just trying out the JavaScript attack strings provided by the question [How to prevent Javascript injection attacks within user-generated HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942011/how-to-prevent-javascript-injection-attacks-within-user-generated-html) and the result of the second string is, that when I paste it into the text-box of the popup "Select your next tag badge" that it freezes my tab and becomes unresponsive (Chrome).

Tried it out in IE 11 with the same result, but IE 11 does let me kill the JavaScript execution. In Chrome I have to close the tab.

Maybe it is a dumb idea to paste such strings in the search box of the popup and I should not do it, but I'm just a user of the site and I want to let you know about this behavior.

Comment: What is the Chrome version?

Comment: @HackerKarma latest stable Desktop version

Comment: Repro'ed, though doubt it will be fixed (whatever the cause is) -- it's a rare case... (+1 anyway :)

Comment: Repro. in Chrome version 45.0.2454.101 (64-bit)... +1

Comment: Does it hit SE's javascript or backend?  May just be the browser's issue and not SE at all.

Comment: Why is there a 'close' vote on this question? I tried this on Meta.SE 'Select your next tag badge' search box. It's a bug on Meta.SE too.